# Upgrading to 16.04 killed the OS. Ubuntu does not start. What to do?

Tags: startup, ubuntu-gnome

I am writin the question from my tiny mobile phone, so forgive for any typo. I let ubuntu to upgrage to 16.04 afew hours ago and now it does not start up.

it prompts:

/dev/sda1: recovering journal
/dev/sda1: clean 651588/4505600 files, 5733269/17992448 blocks

over and over and over again! I waited for like an hour and still nothing! Does it mean i ve lost every picture and data on thr pc? How can i get Ubuntu to start from here?

i will never upgrade any os anymore. always a problem!

Comment: "Does it mean i ve lost every picture and data on thr pc" Not at all. Worst case scenario is that you have to recover your data using a live usb and then reinstall.

Comment: That message is normal and is shown for all of us ;) The problem is what happens next. I assume it is a video card problem. So try to start from GRUB with nomodeset (press F6 in grub so it pops up the options and pick that one). If it does boot you know it is your video card driver. And you did make a backup did you not? ;-) If not boot from a live dvd, mount your disks and do make a backup 1st before you mess with the OS.

Comment: i in grub but there is no command as nomodeset